# Changing the conditions to replace elements in a vector

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, replace, conditional-statements

Consider the vector:

`use = c(1,1,2,2,5,1,2,1,2,5,1)`

I'm trying to replace all the numbers different from 5 to NA before the first number 5 shows up in the sequence: 
`ifelse(use != 5,NA,1)`. 
After that the condition should be 
`ifelse(use != 5,0,1)`.

The output would be:

`after = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1,0,0,0,0,1,0)`

Any tips?

Comment: why is `use` having a length of 11 while `after` has a length of 9? Should there be two ones in `after` since there are two 5's in `use`?

Answer (score 3):

You should try:

```
`is.na<-`(match(use, 5, 0), seq(match(5, use) - 1))
 [1] NA NA NA NA  1  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `match`

```
replace(use, seq_len(match(5, use) - 1), NA)
#[1] NA NA NA NA  5  1  2  1  2  5  1
```

Or as @M-- commented, this can be changed to binary with

```
+(replace(use, seq_len(match(5, use) - 1), NA)==5)
```

Comment: Had a similar idea: `idx <- Position(function(x) x == 5, use); replace(x <- match(use, 5), is.na(x) & seq_len(length(x)) > idx, 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution

```
after <- replace(v<- ifelse(use !=5,NA,1),
        which(head(which(v==1),1)<seq_along(v) & is.na(v)),
        0)
```

such that

```
> after
 [1] NA NA NA NA  1  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: I'd say that this is the only solution that works if the vector doesn't have any target number, in this case, number 5. The other solutions don't replace any of the numbers in case the target number is absent.

Comment: @L.Rattis Great to hear that. Hope my answer is helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

Weird subsetting:

```
c(NA[!cumsum(use == 5)], +(use[!!cumsum(use == 5)] == 5))
#[1] NA NA NA NA  1  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which` to find the location of the target, and then `case_when`

```r
use <- c(1,1,2,2,5,1,2,1,2)

first_five <- min(which(use == 5))
dplyr::case_when(
  seq_along(use) < first_five ~ NA_real_,
  seq_along(use) == first_five ~ 1, 
  TRUE ~ 0
)
#> [1] NA NA NA NA  1  0  0  0  0
use
#> [1] 1 1 2 2 5 1 2 1 2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, @RichardTelford! But I would also need `ifelse(use != 5,0,1)` after the occurrence of the first algorithm 5.

Comment: Fixed now to match required output

Answer (score 1):

This will work if there's only one 5 in your vector

```
use = c(1,1,2,2,5,1,2,2,2)
use <- findInterval(use,5)*5
i <- which(use > 0)
if(i > 1) use[1:(i-1)] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code solves the problem:

```
use[1:(which(use == 5)[1]-1)] = NA
use[(which(use == 5)[1]+1):length(use)] = 0
use[which(use == 5)[1]] = 1
use
[1] NA NA NA NA  1  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Hi @FilipeLauar this solution doesn't work if there's more than one 5 in the vector

Comment: Updated the code with the correct answer. Just add to get the first value in the `which` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variation. I through in some error handling in case there are no 5's in the vector.

```
test1 <-  c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3)
test2 <-  c(5,1,1,2,5,1,2,7,8)
test3 <-  c(1,1,3,5,6,7,8,2)
test4 <-  c(1,2,3,4,5,5,1,5,5,5,1,1,7,8,1)



find_and_replace <- function(vec, target){
  tryCatch(
    ifelse( seq_along(vec) %in% 1:{(which(vec == target)[[1]])-1}, NA, ifelse(vec == 5, 1, 0)),
    error = function(x) {
      warning(paste("Warning: No", target))
      vec
    }
  )
}

find_and_replace(test1, 5)
#> Warning: No 5
#> [1] 1 1 1 1 2 3 3
find_and_replace(test2, 5)
#> [1] NA  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
find_and_replace(test3, 5)
#> [1] NA NA NA  1  0  0  0  0
find_and_replace(test4, 5)
#> [1] NA NA NA NA  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: according to the output, there is only one 1, yet the input has two 5's. Don't you think you should replicate that also?

Answer (score 0):

You could detect the first 5,

```
first_pos <- which(use==5)
```

and, if such elements exist, set all entries before the first occurence to NA:

```
if(length(first_pos)>0) {
    use[seq(1,first_pos[1]-1)] <- NA
    use[seq(1,first_pos[1])] <- 1
    use[seq(first_pos[1]+1, length(use)] <- 0
}
```

Note that `first_pos[1]` is called in case there are more than one 5.